# Ignore system message in Log Cat Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

I am just getting the system message in LogCat. Where as, if i get my current app message then it get flush out(remove from LogCat).

This image will describe the problem which i am facing

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can edit a filter with tag or application name so that you can focus on those logs.

Comment: How can i do that, please how to do that mean where to go and what to select?? please help

Comment: In logcat window, click on '+' icon. it will open a window to add filter. Give some name to filter and add your application name/tag you want to filter in appropriate fields.